# Partial application left to right

Tags: haskell, partial-application

I started with haskell yesterday and am still completely lost on the shore of this brave new world. Now I have run into the following issue:

Let's assume I have some function that does some magic to an integer and another variable:

```
makeTuple :: Int -> a -> (Int, a)
makeTuple n x = (n, x)
```

Now I want to apply this function to all elements of a list. So far no problem, as mapping is your daily bread and butter in python (where I come from), too.

```
makeTupleList :: Int -> [a] -> [ (Int, a) ]
makeTupleList n x = map (makeTuple n) x
```

As far as I understand, the binary function makeTuple is applied partially with the integer n and hence becomes a unary function which can be mapped to each element of x. So far, all is well.

But what do I do when the makeTuple function has another signature, like:

```
makeTuple2 :: a -> Int -> (Int, a)
makeTuple2 x n = (n, x)
```

Many ways lead to Rome: the effect is the same, but the way is another. Now obviously the mapping doesn't work anymore: The function expects an Int and gets an a.

```
makeTupleList2 :: Int -> [a] -> [ (Int, a) ]
makeTupleList2 n x = map (makeTuple2 n) x -- boolshit
```

This was to be expected. My -maybe too pythonic- workaround is using another function to pass the parameters where they should go:

```
makeTupleList2 :: Int -> [a] -> [ (Int, a) ]
makeTupleList2 n x = map (\x -> makeTuple2 x n) x
```

**Question:**
What is the preferred functional, haskell-style way of partially applying functions when the parially applied parameters isn't the leftmost?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `flip`, which swaps the first and second arguments of a function.

```
makeTupleList2 n x = map (flip makeTuple2 n) x
```

Another option is to use the backticks syntax to make an infix operator and then partially apply that using an operator section.

```
maleTupleList2 n x = map (`makeTuple2` n) x
```

Or, as you said we can use a lambda expression. Which one to use depends on context and personal taste. Use whatever you feel is most clear.

---

**PS:** What you're doing is called *partial application*. Currying is the process of transforming a function taking multiple arguments `(a, b) -> c` into *curried form* `a -> b -> c` so that it can be partially applied.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in terminology here. Backticks convert function to an infix operator. Partial application is then performed using the operator section syntax. Backticks have nothing to do with operator section otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `\x -> makeTuple2 x n` with `flip makeTuple2 n`, because the Prelude defines `flip` like: (my implementation, not theirs)

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f y x = f x y
```

Hence we get

```
makeTupleList2' = map . flip makeTuple2
```

Or, seeing as how its just a tuple:

```
makeTupleList2'' = map . (,)
```

Also note (I'm not sure how efficient this is), you could use zip:

```
makeTupleList2''' :: a -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
makeTupleList2''' = zip . repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you could use `flip makeTuple2 n`, but that only works for functions with two arguments. But generally, I don't find your solution with the lambda un-haskelly or too pythonic.

Comment: Actually, suppose in the type of `flip` we substitute `c = d -> e` to get `(a -> b -> d -> e) -> b -> a -> d -> e`. This can be handy if you want a point-free function with more than one parameter. That is, you want to call `flip f b'` and have two point-free parameters.

Comment: More generally, we can define the function `$(rotate n)` where n is the number of parameters, to be analagous to `flip`, by rotating the parameters (I'm not sure if `rotate` is definable via typeclass recursion)

Comment: @camccann Ahh, neat. I never actually tried to define it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are only tuple constructors:

```
makeTuple x y = (x,y)
```

(which can also be written as `makeTuple = (,)`) then there is a special extension for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
makeTupleList2 n x = map (n,) x
makeTupleList2' n x = map (,n) x     -- Use n as the second component
```

which can also be written as

```
makeTupleList2 n = map (n,)
makeTupleList2' n = map (,n)
```

Otherwise use ways already suggested.

Comment: Not correct, it ought to be `makeTupleList2 n = map (n,)`, hence `makeTupleList2 = map . (,)`